# Recycler view crashed while scrolling on resume of activity

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

//    My RecyclerAdpater code here :

```
public static final class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivProperty;
    ImageView ivEditProperty;
    ImageView ivDeleteProperty;
    ImageView ivPropTransHistory;
    ImageView ivInspectReport;
    TextView tvMaintenReqCount;
    TextView tvPropName;
    TextView tvPropAddr;
    TextView tvPropStatus;
    View view;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        //Initialize the variables
        ivProperty = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivProperty);
        tvPropName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPropName);
        tvPropAddr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPropAddr);
        tvPropStatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPropStatus);
        tvMaintenReqCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMaintenReqCount);
        ivEditProperty = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivEditProperty);
        ivPropTransHistory = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivPropTransHistory);
        ivInspectReport = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivInspectReport);
        ivDeleteProperty = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivDeleteProperty);
        view = v;
    }
}

// Recycler adpter 

private final class PropertyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PropertyListActivity.ViewHolder> {

    final Context _context;
    List<PropertyListDTO> objects;

    public PropertyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<PropertyListDTO> objects) {
        this._context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_property_list, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder v = new ViewHolder(view);
        return v;
    }

    public void setFilter(List<PropertyListDTO> list) {
        objects = new ArrayList<PropertyListDTO>();
        objects.addAll(list);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // bindview holder

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your data set at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        String propImgUrl = "";
        final PropertyListDTO p = objects.get(position);
        // Load a bitmap from the drawable folder
        try {
            // set data value

            holder.tvPropName.setText(p.getPropertyName());
            holder.tvPropAddr.setText(p.getAddress());
            if (p.getInspectionReports() != null) {
                if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_0));
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_1));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_2));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.GONE); //holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_3));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_4));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_5));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_6));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (p.getInspectionReports() != null && p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("7")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_7));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_0));
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {

                if (p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_0));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_1));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else if (p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_2));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (p.getPropStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                    holder.tvPropStatus.setText(_context.getResources().getString(R.string.property_status_3));
                    holder.ivEditProperty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.ivInspectReport.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } 


            holder.tvMaintenReqCount.setText("(" + p.getMaintenance_request_count() + ")");
            if (p.getGallery() != null && p.getGallery().size() > 0) {
                propImgUrl = AppConstants.property_Images_Path + p.getGallery().get(0).toString();
            }
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(propImgUrl)) {
                Picasso.with(context).load(propImgUrl).error(R.mipmap.home_profile).into(holder.ivProperty);
            } else {

            }

            android.util.Log.e("ImageUrl List =>", propImgUrl.toString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // click listener  View Property Detail                  

        holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPropDetailsFragment.class);
                intent.putExtra("propDetails", p);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        // Edit Property Detail Info

        holder.ivEditProperty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(PropertyListActivity.this, EditPropPrimDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("propertyListDTO", p);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


        holder.ivPropTransHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                PropertyTransactionFragment propertyTransactionFragment = new PropertyTransactionFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("property_id", p.getId().get$id());
                bundle.putString("p_Id", p.getPropertyId());
                bundle.putString("property_name", p.getPropertyName());
                propertyTransactionFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, propertyTransactionFragment);

                transaction.addToBackStack("propertyTransactionFragment");
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }
}
```

// Log error is :

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.excellenceit.propcare, PID: 9927
                                                                         java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 4(offset:4).state:9
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4957)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4913)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1193)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1043)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1552)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2649)
                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8968)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2698)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2410)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2709)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2425)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2568)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1776)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2866)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2529)
                                                                             at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9173)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4706)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4544)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4201)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4258)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4087)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4068)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl

Comment: can you post your adapter code too

Comment: looks like your datasource does not have the same number of items as your  recycler view expects

Comment: I have post question with source code.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the position in your `onBindViewHolder` like your data list or data array might not have any data for that position.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Finally I got the answers of the above question and follow the steps :

1) Create the templist as arraylist using your modelclass.

2) Assigned the templist to the arraylist which is passed to the RecyclerAdapter.

```
private List<PropertyListDTO> propertyList;
List<PropertyListDTO> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
```

// Parsing Json data

```
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("properties");
 if (array.length() > 0) {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  int i = 0;
  while (i < array.length()) {
  tempList.add(gson.fromJson(array.getJSONObject(i).toString(), PropertyListDTO.class));
  i++;
  }

  // assign the templist to the adpapterlist

  propertyList = tempList;
  if (propertyList.size() > 0) {
  mAdapter = new PropertyRecyclerAdapter(PropertyListActivity.this, propertyList);
  mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
}
```

//Using this the index of RecyclerAdapter is rearrange itself and scrolling smoothly.